# NDSolve Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions error

Tags: differential-equations

Initially tried to solve following first degree of differential equations using following method

```
solA = NDSolve[{ eqA, incA}, varA, {τ, 0, 1000},AccuracyGoal -> 35, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 35, WorkingPrecision -> 45,MaxSteps -> ∞]
```

and encountered the error,`Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at τ == 0.`
Later introduced `SolveDelayed -> True`
then encountered the error `For the method NDSolveIDA, only machine real code is available. Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions.`

Please purpose some method to remove these errors and obtain solution for given equations. It will be very helpuful if someone will also explain cause of the above errors.
Thanks in anticipation.

Code is as following

```
(*====== Physical Parameters======= *)
 w[t_] := 0; 
 β[t_] := 0; 
 m = 2350; ms = 7920; Js = 4495; l = 11/10; h = 178/100; hs = 19/10; 
 a = 24/20; c = 1500; 
 k = 2200000; g = 98/10; di = 24/10; θc = ArcCos[l/di]; 


(*=====Variable defined=====*)
ρ = Sqrt[Js/ms]; μ = m/ms; ζ = c/(ms ωs); ζp = cp/(ms ωs); λ1 = a/l; λ2 =h/l;
λ3 = hs /l ; λ4 = ρ/l; ωs = Sqrt[(2 k)/ms]; ωp = Sqrt[g/l]; ω0 = ωp/ωs;

α1 = -λ1^2 - λ2 μ ω0^2 + λ2^2 μ ω0^2 - λ3 ω0^2 + λ4^2 ω0^2;
α2 = -λ1^2 + λ2 μ ω0^2 - λ2^2 μ ω0^2 - λ3 ω0^2 - λ4^2 ω0^2;
α3 = λ1^2 λ4^2 ω0^2 - λ2 λ4^2 μ ω0^4 + λ3 λ4^2 ω0^4; 
α4 = -λ1^2 + λ1^2 λ2 - λ3 ω0^2 + λ2 λ3 ω0^2 + λ4^2 ω0^2;
α5 =  α1 + Sqrt[α2^2 - 4 α3];    α6 =  α1 - Sqrt[α2^2 - 4 α3];  

e11  = -(α6/Sqrt[μ (2 α4 - (1 - λ2) α6)^2 + λ4^2 α6^2]);   
e12  = -((2 α4)/Sqrt[μ (2 α4 - (1 - λ2) α6)^2 + λ4^2 α6^2]); 
e21  = -(α5/Sqrt[μ (2 α4 - (1 - λ2) α5)^2 + λ4^2 α5^2]); 
e22  = -((2 α4)/Sqrt[μ (2 α4 - (1 - λ2) α5)^2 + λ4^2 α5^2]);

(*=========Equations to be Solved==========*)
eqA1 = A1'[τ] + e11^2 ζ λ1^2 A1[τ]+(e12^2 A1[τ] (4 ζp θc^2 + 
  d0 e12^2 l^2 A1[τ]^2 + 2 d0 e22^2 l^2 A2[τ]^2))/(8 l^2 θc^2);

eqA2 = A2'[τ] + e21^2 ζ λ1^2 A2[τ]+(e22^2 A2[τ] (4 ζp θc^2 + 
  d0 e22^2 l^2 A2[τ]^2 + 2 d0 e12^2 l^2 A1[τ]^2))/(8 l^2 θc^2);

eqAz = Az'[τ] + (ζ Az[τ])/(1 + μ);

(*=========Method Used to solve these Equations==========*)
eqA = {eqA1 == 0, eqA2 == 0, eqAz == 0};
incA = {Az[0] == 4/100, A1[0] == 2/10, A2[0] == 3/10};
varA = {Az, A1, A2};
eq  = Flatten@Solve[eqA,{D[Az[τ],τ],D[A1[τ],τ],D[A2[τ], τ]}] /. Rule -> Equal;
solA = NDSolve[{ eqA, incA}, varA, {τ, 0, 1000},AccuracyGoal -> 35, PrecisionGoal -> 35, WorkingPrecision -> 45,MaxSteps -> ∞, SolveDelayed -> True]
```

Comment: Just removed AccuracyGoal, PrecisionGoal and Working Precision value and it gives solution but is there any method to solve it with desired AccuracyGoal, PrecisionGoal and Working Precision values as mentioned in above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all let us simplify the equations in order to get an overwiev of their structure.

Letting `Az->f, A1->g, A2->h, τ --> t (1 + μ)/ζ` the equations become

```
eq1 = 0 == f'[t] + f[t];
eq2 = 0 == g'[t] + a[1] g[t] + a[2] g[t]^3 + a[3] g[t] h[t]^2;
eq3 = 0 == h'[t] + b[1] h[t] + b[2] h[t]^3 + b[3] h[t] g[t]^2;
```

Here `a[]` and `b[]` are real parameters each of which is defined by a specific combination of the original parameters (to be done by the reader). It seems they are all positive.

We can see immediately that `f` is decoupled from `g` and `h`, and that it is given by a simple decaying exponential.

Linearizing the equations for `g` and `h` also lead to complete decoupling and exponential decay.

The stationary solution is given by `f == 0` and

```
Reduce[{0 == a[1] g[t] + a[2] g[t]^3 + a[3] g[t] h[t]^2,
   0 == b[1] h[t] + b[2] h[t]^3 + b[3] h[t] g[t]^2}, {f[t], g[t], h[t]}];
```

Obviously zero is a solution for `g` and `h` as well.

Instead of attempting a deeper analytic study we turn (for simplicity) to a numerical Monte-Carlo approach taking the parameters as real positive random values and assume random numbers between -1 and +1 for the initial values. We don't consider f[t] as it is trivial.

```
r := RandomReal[]
```

You can experiment repeating the following code

```
Table[{a[i] = r, b[i] = r}, {i, 1, 3}];
sol = {g[t], h[t]} /. 
   NDSolve[{eq2, eq3, g[0] == 2 r - 1, h[0] == 2 r - 1}, {g[t], h[t]}, {t, 0, 10}][[1]];
Plot[sol, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The original system should be soluble numerically with "reasonable" parameters.

Comment: this works for specific parameters, please explain cause of errors encountered while solving equations in terms of original parameters.   Please suggest some method to solve it with original parameters as they can not be changed.

Comment: Was able to solve without AccuracyGoal, PrecisionGoal and Working Precision values as mentioned in comment box of question. Can we solve it by desired value of AccuracyGoal, PrecisionGoal and Working Precision values.

Comment: @Bikramjit Here's my suggestion: please give the values of the parameters a[] and b[] according to your problem, NDSolve the system and point out where you see difficulties with accuracy.

Comment: Wolfgang Thank you  it is solvable with this formulation, if possible can you explain reason why it is solvable with this formulation but failed with previous one for high WorkingPrecison.

Comment: @Bikramjit  Honestly, I don't know. I'm not an expert in questions of numerical precision.